# ASP.NET User Control - Change Style of Div based on Color Scheme Choice

Tags: .net, user-controls

I have a created a user control that is hopefully going to be used across several sites. The problem that I am having is that these sites may all have different color schemes. I was wondering how I might be able to make a template for the control, and then based on the developer's site, they will pass a parameter that indicates the color scheme they require, and the user control will update appropriately. I am very new to .NET, so please bear with me if this is a trivial question. I tried researching online, but most examples were either more complex, or just changed colors of panels, instead of changing css styles.

The control (.ascx) is as listed below:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EmployeeSearch.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_EmployeeSearch" ClassName="EmployeeSearch" %>

<div id="divUserEntry" runat="server">
    <center>
        <br />
        <!-- This is the title for the employee search-->
        <div id="employeeTitle" class="LookupTitle">
            <center>Select Employee</center>
        </div>
        <!-- Div for the actual search elements -->   
        <div id="searchPeople" class="searchPeople">
            <div id="addedPerson" class="addedPerson">
            </div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserEntry" class="searchTextBox" runat="server" Text="Enter Name or ID" onFocus="this.value = ''" CssClass="searchTextStyle"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="currentSearch" name="currentSearch" Value="notANormalValue" />

            <div id="searchResults" class="searchResults">
                Search for employee to manage.
            </div> 
        </div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmitEmployee" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    </center>
</div>
```

Then I register it like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="EmployeeSearch" Src="~/Controls/EmployeeSearch.ascx" %>
```

and just call it with this:

```
<uc:EmployeeSearch ID="searchContent" runat="server" />
```

I know that I can add a property in the uc call, but I am not sure what to do to get the divs to update correctly. Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usercontrols inherit the css from the aspx or site.master pages so what you could do is in each css either add

```
#divUserEntry{color:#fff;}
```

or set a css class and then your div

```
<div id="divUserEntry" runat="server" class="usercontrol">
```

but still in each css they have to add

```
.usercontrol{color:#fff;}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The divUserEntry is in my custom user control. I will create all the css classes, but how do I pass the parameter for which class I want to use? I guess the analogy would be if I had a class constructor and passed a parameter called scheme, the constructor would set the UI based on the value of Scheme. I'm just unsure of how to pass that parameter in this way, and then do what you suggested (i.e. set the class properly).

Comment: according to what you specified is that this usercontrol will be used in several sites, I am assuming that each site has it's own css file? if so then each css file needs to either include the #divUserEntry with formatting or the class name with formatting..if not you should be able to set the css class by codebehind on the page that is loading it which is another option.